# can't compile FBReaderJ

Tags: android, ant, build-process

Solved: **The problem was: wrong version of Java. See my comments.**

Hi all,
using fbreaderj-0.7.17 sources, and Android SDK update manager (Platform tools rev8, 1.6 SDK rev 3).

After `ant compile`, get the errors:

```
-pre-build:

-resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
     [null] /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/platform-tools/aapt: /lib32/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/platform-tools/aapt)
     [null] /tmp/FBReaderJ-sources-0.7.17/res/layout/main.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fadeScrollbars' in package 'android'

BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:306: null returned: 1
```

Targets:

```
/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/android list targets
Available Android targets:
id: 1 or "android-4"
     Name: Android 1.6
     Type: Platform
     API level: 4
     Revision: 3
     Skins: QVGA, HVGA (default), WVGA800, WVGA854
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:4"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 1.6 (API level 4)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WVGA854, HVGA (default), WVGA800, QVGA
```

Project update:

> /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/android
>   update project --name FBReaderJ --path
>   . --target 1

local.properties:

> sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-update-manager
>
> ndk.dir=/opt/android-ndk-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the main.xml file uses android:fadeScrollbars attribute that is not part of the API level you are using to build the project. I think you should use at least API level 5 to use that atribute.

Comment: Tried to build with 2.1 (API level 7) target, `[null] /tmp/FBReaderJ-sources-0.7.17/res/layout/main.xml:8: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fadeScrollbars' in package 'android'`

Comment: I don't know where that attribute comes from. You can of course just remove it from main.xml. It shouldn't change the functionality that much.

Comment: Would try later, seems to be a partial solution for backward compatibility. However, the answer was to change 1) system's java vm from JRE to JDK's one 2) replace open Icedtea J** with Sun... funny, now it makes my Eclipse CDT to crash often :))

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (tested)

steps:

1. `/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/android update project --name FBReaderJ --path . --target 2`

   (you have to be on 1.6 and onwards. For 1.5 there is a different branch)
2. from res\layout\main.xml remove the "fadeScrollbars" line
3. from Android manifest you need to remove this: `android:installLocation="auto"`
4. clean and rebuild (either by eclipse or with ant clean & ant release (or ant package)

For point 3. - also see this note about [backward compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity)!